# Why does this "endless" loop end?

Tags: magento-enterprise

I've added in the following to `Mage.php` in order to trace some events.

```
public static function dispatchEvent($name, array $data = array())
{
    ...
    Mage::log('--> Event dispatched: ' . $name);   // event name
    ...
}
```

When clicking on "Save Config" in any admin->System->Configuration tab, it causes a loop because it seems like `Mage::log()` eventually triggers `Abstract::_beforeLoad()`, which in turn also calls `Mage::dispatchEvet()`, causing a loop. However, I'm not seeing why this loop ends and enters a different sequence of events (trace line 92). Any ideas? I'm using Magento EE 1.13.

```
Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php on line 108

Call Stack:
    0.0001     687728   1. {main}() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/index.php:0
    0.0016    1198080   2. Mage::run() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/index.php:87
    0.0056    2848264   3. Mage_Core_Model_App->run() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:684
    0.5489   17667160   4. Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:354
    0.5567   19353728   5. Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:172
    0.5626   20142472   6. Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php:250
    0.7081   26153848   7. Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController->saveAction() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php:418
    1.8606   32395016   8. Mage_Core_Model_App->reinitStores() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/ConfigController.php:174
    1.8606   32395016   9. Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:593
    1.8613   32424656  10. Varien_Data_Collection->count() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:624
    1.8613   32424656  11. Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Store_Collection->load() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php:752
    1.8613   32425568  12. Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Store/Collection.php:174
    1.8613   32425568  13. Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->_beforeLoad() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php:559
    1.8613   32425992  14. Mage::dispatchEvent() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php:586
    1.8613   32426120  15. Mage::log() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:446
    1.8613   32426376  16. Mage::getStoreConfig() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:792
    1.8613   32426424  17. Mage_Core_Model_App->getStore() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:352
    1.8614   32432400  18. Mage_Core_Model_Store->load() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:838
    1.8614   32432400  19. Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php:268
    1.8614   32432400  20. Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_beforeLoad() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php:224
    1.8614   32432992  21. Mage::dispatchEvent() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php:253
    1.8614   32433096  22. Mage::log() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:446
    1.8614   32433352  23. Mage::getStoreConfig() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:792
    1.8614   32433400  24. Mage_Core_Model_App->getStore() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:352
    1.8614   32439376  25. Mage_Core_Model_Store->load() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:838
    1.8614   32439376  26. Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php:268
    1.8614   32439376  27. Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_beforeLoad() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php:224
    1.8614   32439968  28. Mage::dispatchEvent() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php:253
    1.8614   32440072  29. Mage::log() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:446
    1.8614   32440328  30. Mage::getStoreConfig() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:792
    1.8615   32440376  31. Mage_Core_Model_App->getStore() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:352
    1.8615   32446352  32. Mage_Core_Model_Store->load() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:838
    1.8615   32446352  33. Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php:268
    1.8615   32446352  34. Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_beforeLoad() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php:224
    1.8615   32446944  35. Mage::dispatchEvent() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php:253
    1.8615   32447048  36. Mage::log() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:446
    1.8615   32447304  37. Mage::getStoreConfig() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:792
    1.8615   32447352  38. Mage_Core_Model_App->getStore() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:352
    1.8615   32453328  39. Mage_Core_Model_Store->load() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:838
    1.8615   32453328  40. Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php:268
    1.8616   32453328  41. Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_beforeLoad() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php:224
    1.8616   32453920  42. Mage::dispatchEvent() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php:253
    1.8616   32454024  43. Mage::log() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:446
    1.8616   32454280  44. Mage::getStoreConfig() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:792
    1.8616   32454328  45. Mage_Core_Model_App->getStore() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:352
    1.8616   32460304  46. Mage_Core_Model_Store->load() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:838
    1.8616   32460304  47. Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php:268
    1.8616   32460304  48. Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_beforeLoad() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php:224
    1.8616   32460896  49. Mage::dispatchEvent() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php:253
    1.8616   32461000  50. Mage::log() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:446
    1.8616   32461256  51. Mage::getStoreConfig() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:792
    1.8616   32461304  52. Mage_Core_Model_App->getStore() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:352
    1.8617   32467280  53. Mage_Core_Model_Store->load() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:838
    1.8617   32467280  54. Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php:268
    1.8617   32467280  55. Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_beforeLoad() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php:224
    1.8617   32467872  56. Mage::dispatchEvent() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php:253
    1.8617   32467976  57. Mage::log() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:446
    1.8617   32468232  58. Mage::getStoreConfig() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:792
    1.8617   32468280  59. Mage_Core_Model_App->getStore() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:352
    1.8617   32474256  60. Mage_Core_Model_Store->load() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:838
    1.8617   32474256  61. Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php:268
    1.8617   32474256  62. Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_beforeLoad() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php:224
    1.8617   32474848  63. Mage::dispatchEvent() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php:253
    1.8617   32474952  64. Mage::log() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:446
    1.8617   32475208  65. Mage::getStoreConfig() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:792
    1.8617   32475256  66. Mage_Core_Model_App->getStore() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:352
    1.8618   32481248  67. Mage_Core_Model_Store->load() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:838
    1.8618   32481248  68. Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php:268
    1.8618   32481248  69. Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_beforeLoad() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php:224
    1.8618   32481840  70. Mage::dispatchEvent() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php:253
    1.8618   32481944  71. Mage::log() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:446
    1.8618   32482200  72. Mage::getStoreConfig() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:792
    1.8618   32482248  73. Mage_Core_Model_App->getStore() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:352
    1.8618   32488256  74. Mage_Core_Model_Store->load() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:838
    1.8618   32488256  75. Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php:268
    1.8618   32488256  76. Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_beforeLoad() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php:224
    1.8618   32488848  77. Mage::dispatchEvent() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php:253
    1.8618   32488960  78. Mage::log() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:446
    1.8618   32489248  79. Mage::getStoreConfig() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:792
    1.8618   32489304  80. Mage_Core_Model_App->getStore() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:352
    1.8619   32495528  81. Mage_Core_Model_Store->load() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:838
    1.8619   32495528  82. Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php:268
    1.8619   32495528  83. Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_beforeLoad() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php:224
    1.8619   32496120  84. Mage::dispatchEvent() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php:253
    1.8619   32496224  85. Mage::log() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:446
    1.8619   32496480  86. Mage::getStoreConfig() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:792
    1.8619   32496528  87. Mage_Core_Model_App->getStore() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:352
    1.8619   32502520  88. Mage_Core_Model_Store->load() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:838
    1.8619   32502520  89. Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php:268
    1.8619   32502520  90. Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_beforeLoad() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php:224
    1.8619   32503112  91. Mage::dispatchEvent() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php:253
    1.8619   32503216  92. Mage::log() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:446
    1.8619   32503472  93. Mage::getStoreConfig() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:792
    1.8619   32503520  94. Mage_Core_Model_App->getStore() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:352
    1.8619   32503600  95. Mage::getModel() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:833
    1.8619   32503816  96. Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/Mage.php:463
    1.8620   32507288  97. Varien_Object->__construct() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php:1348
    1.8620   32507808  98. Mage_Core_Model_Store->_construct() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/lib/Varien/Object.php:112
    1.8620   32507888  99. Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_init() /home/my_user/public_html/store_name/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php:226
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a different sequence, although it's easy to get confused and think it is.

What you're looking at above is a [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack), and not an [execution trace](http://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace).  A call stack doesn't list every method called in a program, it lists every method called to reach a certain point in the code.

If we consider the "standard" sequence of seven method calls, it might look like this

```
Mage::dispatchEvent()
Mage::log()
Mage::getStoreConfig()
Mage_Core_Model_App->getStore()
Mage_Core_Model_Store->load()
Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load()
Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_beforeLoad()
```

However, a better representation of that might be the following

```
Mage::dispatchEvent()
    Mage::log()
        Mage::getStoreConfig()
            Mage_Core_Model_App->getStore()
                Mage_Core_Model_Store->load()
                    Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load()
                        Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_beforeLoad()
```

The `dispatchEvent` method calls the `log` method, which called the `getStoreConfig` method, etc.

If we take a look at the "non standard " sequence

```
Mage::dispatchEvent()
Mage::log()
Mage::getStoreConfig()
Mage_Core_Model_App->getStore()
Mage::getModel()
Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance()
Varien_Object->__construct()
Mage_Core_Model_Store->_construct()
Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_init()
```

We can see they start the same, but then differ after `getStore` is called

```
Mage::dispatchEvent()
Mage::log()
Mage::getStoreConfig()
Mage_Core_Model_App->getStore()
Mage::getModel()
```

Except — they don't differ.  The reason it looks like they differ is PHP has halted execution in the middle of a call sequence.  What normally happens looks like this

```
Mage_Core_Model_App->getStore()
    Mage::getModel()
        Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance()
            Varien_Object->__construct()
                Mage_Core_Model_Store->_construct()
                    Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_init()
                    ... some unknown number of method calls
Mage_Core_Model_Store->load()
```

That is, `getStore` calls `Mage::getModel` — but then method execution chain  finishes, comes back to the `getStore` level, and then calls `Mage_Core_Model_Store->load()` which triggers "the standard" sequence.

Because PHP (or more specifically, xDebug) buts in to stop this run-away call chain, the call stack is halted in the middle of the `Mage::getModel` call, which normally doesn't register in the endless loop.

Also, re-your event tracking, I have a text auto complete snippet that expands to

```
$message = '';
file_put_contents('/tmp/developer.log', $message, FILE_APPEND);
```

for poor man's logging.  There's also (SHAMELESS PLUG) [Commerce Bug's events tab](http://commercebugdemo.pulsestorm.net/), which displays a list of events.