# Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!

Tags: php, event-observer, error

after adding module i get below error

Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!

i have seen lots of solution availble for it

i tried to change php.ini inside my folder and set 
max_nesting_level = 200

still getting same error and could not find any such line in my php.ini file "max_nesting_level "

what have i to do to make it work

below is my code for observer

```
    public function loadaftercatalog(Varien_Event_Observer $event) {
        if($_GET['id']){
            $_producttoadd=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_GET['id'])->getPrice();// if i remove this line it works fine

            $product = $event->getEvent()->getProduct();
            $originalprice = $product->getPrice();
            $customprice = $originalprice+$pricetoadd;
            $product->setPrice($customprice);
        }
   }
```

/********************************************************************/
    For solution check :

```
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/50244/observer-getting-called-more-than-once
```

Comment: See also: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10430/why-does-this-endless-loop-end and http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9973/maximum-function-nesting-level-of-1000-reached-aborting

Comment: I believe you got your answer here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/50244/observer-getting-called-more-than-once

Comment: yeah ..................