# observer getting called more than once

Tags: module, event-observer, magento-1

i wrote below observer to add extra price to product price based on get paramter id of product

```
 <catalog_product_load_after>
            <observers>
                <setcustomprice>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Mour_Customgroup_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>loadaftercatalog</method>
                </setcustomprice>
            </observers>
    </catalog_product_load_after>
```

observer.php

```
    public function loadaftercatalog(Varien_Event_Observer $event) {

            $pricetoadd=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(233); // error caused after adding this line

            $product = $event->getEvent()->getProduct();
            $originalprice = $product->getPrice();
            $customprice = $originalprice+$pricetoadd->->getPrice();
            $product->setPrice($customprice);

   }
```

after adding code to observer i keep on getting error maximum nesting level of 500 reachesd i thing my observer i getting called more than once any better way to solve the issue

pls suggest

What i am trying to do :

1: there are two categories A, B 
if user browser any product of A he has option to buy it with any other product in B

so i pass id of product in A via get parameter and show Products of category B with added price based on id of product in get parameter

Comment: `if($_GET['id']){}` This wrong

Comment: why soo i am passing id of product in get parameter

Comment: you can get your Current Product Id using `$observer ->getProduct();` you will get the product detail you do not required to load product again

Comment: no i passing id of some other product also and want to add price of that product to cureent product

Comment: then use `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams()` for fetching request data

Comment: ok see my updated code put static product is ,still same issue if i put $pricetoadd= 100 or $pricetoadd= rand();

it works fine

Comment: I have Update Question please try this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The event `catalog_product_load_after` is dispatched when calling `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::load`.
In your code you call inside the observer

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(233);
```

This will again dispatch the event `catalog_product_load_after` that will call the same code as above and will again dispatch the same event...and it will do this until it get tired.  Apparently it gets tired after 500 loops.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here, but for sure there is a better option.

but if you insist in using the code you have you can do something to stop your code from being executed when you call the second load.

Something like this:

```
public function loadaftercatalog(Varien_Event_Observer $event) {
    $product = $event->getEvent()->getProduct();
    if (!$product->getSkipCustomPriceObserver()) {
        $pricetoadd = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                          ->setSkipCustomPriceObserver(true) //this will set a flag that will be handled by the if statement above. If this flag is true your code will not be executed.
                          ->load(233); 
        $originalprice = $product->getPrice();
        $customprice = $originalprice+$pricetoadd->->getPrice();
        $product->setPrice($customprice);
     }
}
```

Comment: and then discard my answer.....need to type faster next time :)

Comment: @DavidManners. I enhanced my typing and copy-pasting skills these last 2 weeks while on vacation :)

Comment: I on the other hand forgot how to use a computer over the last two weeks.

Comment: @DavidManners to be frank marius answering rate decreased after he turned into moderator.

Comment: @dh47 Are you stalking me? :)

Comment: thanks a lot its working , but just for knowledge any other better way to use some other observer that catalog_product_load_after

Comment: @mour Like I said in the answer, I don't understand what are you trying to achieve. If you wan't to add to all the product prices the price of a specific product then in my opinion you should write a cron that actually updates the prices and get rid of this observer. This way there is no overhead when displaying the prices and you have consistency over the application.

Comment: @Marius no I'm saying that you got busy :)

Comment: @Marius I just want to load category id's and website, my workout -> $category_products  = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array('680','894','895')))
        ->setWebsiteId(2);       still my observer not working.